# How to separate Stored Procedures (i.e. all the business logic) from Client Database so that it only contains client data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

**Scenario**:
Our application database (in SQL Server 2012) contains entire business logic in stored procedures. Every time we have to publish the database to the client, it unnecessarily results in copying the stored procedures to the client database.

**Problem**:
All the business logic gets copied to the client side and results in proprietary issues.

**Solutions tried earlier**:

1. Using `WITH ENCRYPTION`

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE Proc_Name WITH ENCRYPTION
   ```

   This method results in encrypted and non-maintainable stored procedure code. We cannot judge which version of code is running at the client side, hence cannot debug. Version control cannot be applied. Moreover, client cannot perform database replication since encrypted stored procedures do not get replicated.
2. Creating synonyms

   ```
   CREATE SYNONYM SchemaName.Proc_Name FOR LinkedServerDB.SchemaName.Proc_Name
   ```

   This allows for creation of references (synonyms) at `Client_DB` which access the actual stored procedures residing on a `Remote_Linked_Server_DB`. In each stored procedure call, entire data is accessed from `Client_DB` and transmitted to `Remote_Linked_Server_DB` where the calculations are done and the result is sent back. This results in acute performance issues. Also requires 24x7 internet connectivity to the remote linked server.

**Requirement**
We are looking for a solution whereby the stored procedure code could be compiled (secured) and separated from the client database. Also, the compiled stored procedure code should be available at the client-end so that client does not require 24x7 connection to a remote location for accessing the stored procedures. Maybe Visual Studio database projects could be used to compile stored procedure code or something else.

[Edit]
I got to know that SQL Server 2014 allows for natively compiled stored procedure code. Can that be of help? [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133184.aspx/) And is the SQL Server 2014 RTM version stable enough?

Comment: Contrary to common beliefs, stored procedures are **NOT** compiled in SQL Server. When they're deployed, they're stored *in plain text* in the SQL Server system catalogs, and then first used, a stored procedure is treated by the query optimizer like any other statement, and a suitable execution plan is constructed and then cached. If you need to *secure* your stored procedure code, then using `WITH ENCRYPTION` is your only viable option.

Comment: If the code is deployed on a server that the clients control, they *will* be able to access it sooner or later. The more effort your pour into trying to stop that from happening, the less resource you have available to expend on features that clients actually care about - so you wind up delivering a poorer product.

Comment: @marc_s But encrypting the stored procedure code results in issues as highlighted in the question.

Comment: I did see that - so in the end this means: you **CANNOT** encrypt your stored procedure code, so you'll have to either live with that situation, or stop using stored procedures.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Even though I agree with you, our company wishes to keep the code secured and not openly available in the SPs.

Comment: Bring the stored procedures into a data access layer of your compiled application.

Comment: @BeachAndBytes - How can we do that?

Comment: What language is your application written in?

Comment: You could stop using T-SQL stored procedures and instead rewrite them all to C#/VB.NET code; either use this in your application, or deploy them as SQL-CLR stored procedures. But even then: if your client is admin on that SQL Server box, they can extract the compiled .NET assembly from SQL Server and decompile it .....

Comment: Application is written in VB.Net. We are using Visual Studio 2008. We are also planning an upgrade to Visual Studio 2013, if that helps

Comment: You could move the stored procedure logic to queries in your VB.net code but your performance would suffer. Unfortunately .Net assemblies are easily disassembled so this only adds a slight layer of obfuscation, it is probably not worth the time. If your customers have access to the database and your .Net executable there is not much you can do to protect your code.

Comment: @marc_s I am afraid if re-writing all stored procedures would be viable. Is there any tool that could convert T-SQL into SQL-CLR code?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I don't think there's anything readily available to convert T-SQL into VB.NET code....

Comment: I just got to know that SQL Server 2014 allows for natively compiled stored procedure code. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn133184.aspx). Can this help?

Comment: Why can't you apply version control? Don't see a real reason mentioned there. Is it because it adds an overhead to your internal releases management?

Comment: Because encrypted stored procedures cannot be decrypted. How can we apply version control on encrypted procedures? Also how can be debug them?

Comment: OK, that means that you debug on-site. If you debug on copies of the production databases then I see no reason in encrypting them and having a per-SP versioning table. When you need to debug just use the unencrypted versions.

Comment: Also, you can automate the versioning mechanism with [DDL triggers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941(v=sql.105).aspx). When you release, just snapshot the database to a DACPAC (by using `SQLPackage.exe` and store it in your VCS.

Comment: The SQL Server 2014 **native compiled stored procedure** only work with the **in-memory tables**, as far as I know. You cannot use natively compiled stored procedures for "regular" tables in your database.

Comment: @marc_s: Indeed, that seems to [be the case (first paragraph)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn249342.aspx).

Comment: @marceln : Sounds like encryption is the only way. Thanks for highlighting the DACPAC concept.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Let me post this as an answer later so I can get Internet points.

Comment: @IshGoel it is trivial to decrypt a stored procedure. Encrypting stored procedures causes far more pain to the developers than it will ever prevent.

Comment: @SeanLange: Then what is the solution?

Comment: I have heard many arguments over the years that such and such process is proprietary. Unless you are doing high level government work or nasa trajectory calculations it usually isn't that hard to reverse engineer most processes anyway. I have heard people say their stuff is super sensitive and the reality it that is just some simple math. The point is, if the logic is on the server you really can't protect it. If you are really that concerned about it create services that you host which can be called from the client. Otherwise accept that your code is going to be interpreted by somebody.